# Egyptian fraction representations of 1

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, rational-numbers, open-ended-function

An Egyptian fraction is a representation of a rational number using the sum of distinct unit fractions (a unit fraction is of the form \$ \frac 1 x \$ where \$ x \$ is a positive integer).

For all<sup>**[1]**</sup> positive integers \$ n \ne 2 \$, there exists at least one Egyptian fraction of \$ n \$ distinct positive integers whose sum is \$ 1 \$. For example, for \$ n = 4 \$:
$$ \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 6 + \frac 1 {12} = 1 $$
Here is another possible output:
$$ \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {15} = 1 $$

The number of possible outputs is given by [A006585](https://oeis.org/A006585) in the OEIS.

<sup>**[1]**</sup>: I cannot find a direct proof of this, but I can find [a proven lower bound](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/80_11_number_theory.pdf) on A006585, which has this as an obvious consequence. If you can find (or write!) a better / more direct proof that a representation exists for all \$ n \ne 2 \$ I would love to hear it.

### Task

Given \$ n \$, output a list of positive integers representing the denominators of *at least one* valid solution of length \$ n \$.

You may alternatively output a list of rational numbers which are unit fractions, but only if they are an exact representation of the value (so not floating-point).

### Test cases

I only list a few possible outputs. [Here is a Ruby program which can verify any solution](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN00LSkuKNdJTS4r1igtyMks0lHQUlDT1chMLqmsyaxQMixT0FTL1SvLji2r1iktzFWxtgWKaEM1QMxbcVDOy0FEwMtFRMATShqZADGIbAbGBjoKljgJQ1FxHwQyiHAA).

```
n     outputs
1     {1}
3     {2, 3, 6}
4     {2, 4, 6, 12} or {2, 3, 10, 15} or {2, 3, 9, 18} or {2, 4, 5, 20} or {2, 3, 8, 24} or {2, 3, 7, 42} or ...
5     {2, 4, 10, 12, 15} or {2, 4, 9, 12, 18} or {3, 4, 5, 6, 20} or {2, 5, 6, 12, 20} or {2, 4, 8, 12, 24} or {2, 4, 7, 14, 28} or ...
8     {4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 20} or {3, 5, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20} or {3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 15, 18, 24} or {4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 24} or {3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24} or {4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 18, 20, 24} or ...
15    {6, 8, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 28, 30, 33, 35} or {7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 28, 30, 33, 36} or {6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 28, 30, 33, 36} or {6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 28, 33, 35, 36} or {5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 28, 33, 35, 36} or {5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 21, 22, 24, 28, 30, 33, 35, 36} or ...
```

### Rules

- You may output the numbers in any order
- If you choose to output all possible solutions, or a particular subset of them, you must not output duplicates. This includes lists which are the same under some permutation.
- You may assume \$ n \$ is a positive integer, and is not \$ 2 \$
- Your code does not need to practically handle very high \$ n \$, but it must work in theory for all \$ n \$ for which a solution exists
- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24284)

Comment: An inductive proof can work like this:  There is a solution for \$n=3\$, \$\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 6\$.  If we have a solution for \$n=i\$ there is also a solution for \$n=i+2\$, simply take the smallest fraction and replace it with itself multiplied by the solution for \$n=3\$, since it was the smallest and all the resulting fractions are smaller than it all the resulting fractions must be unique.  And the whole sum is still 1.  Now with the base cases of \$n=3\$ and \$n=4\$ we use induction to show every \$n>2\$ has a solution.

Comment: @WheatWizard nice one! dingledooper found a better inductive proof, replacing the smallest fraction 1/n with 1/(n+1) + 1/n(n+1)

Comment: Another inductive proof: if x1, x2, ..., xn is the solution for n, then: 2, 2*x1, 2*x2, ..., 2*xn is a solution for n+1. (in other words, replace all fractions 1/m with 1/2m and add 1/2.)

Comment: some decomposition of the last argument could increase too much

Answer (score 30):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=1:1/n*[x]or[x+1]+f(n-1,x*-~x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc29DsIgGIXh3as4DgToj/Xr2IQraTpgEMXoR0M64OKtI2wn7/Cc/Xs8I8@lePO2n5uz4CEbWmjibs1bTGvuaeu94pGG3I2/rIuPCYzASJYfd0UD6KqXE4Kv@Www1409BT4ghYOREFWFRA95ecXAStIkXMsODXMNqxdalz8)

The key thing to observe is that `1/n = 1/(n+1) + 1/(n*(n+1))`. Therefore we can always obtain a solution with `n` fractions, by using a solution with `n-1` fractions, and "splitting" the last fraction in two.

Comment: dingledoopper big brain i luv the solution +1

Comment: @pxeger ZaMoC had arrived at the same solution it seems, although we both found them independently.

Comment: Very nice! My [Haskell attempt](https://tio.run/##JcsxCoQwEEbhq/zFFjOmMcU2C@NFQorAGJTRQVbL3D0Kdo8P3lJOm7et9wqDQ5tPKik3FXFJKecWp1H2cpD9mCpZiEw@WFAmG5Q5hBeft@9ldQiO/@oXPriKzfg@URExIvYb) actually produced the same solutions (with bruteforcing), but I failed to see the pattern

Comment: Great, great solution! When crafting my original ungolfed one, I found out that a lot of the denominators that were being returned were similar or the same, for instance with n=5 the last fraction was 1/1806, and with n=6 the last fraction was 1/1807 and the last one was like 3.26 million, like in yours, but I failed to notice the pattern (how stupid of me).

Answer (score 13):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
¡ɾṗ'Ė∑1=;t
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCocm+4bmXJ8SW4oiRMT07dCIsIiIsIjMiXQ==)

Bruteforcer. \$O\left(2^{n!}\right)\$ time complexity, searches for fractions with reciprocals \$ n! \$ which seems to be enough.

```
¡          # Factorial
 ɾṗ        # All combinations of 1...n
   '    ;  # Filtered by...
    Ė∑     # Sum of reciprocals
      1=   # is 1?
         t # Get the last one
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! This is a great first post, and I hope you enjoy your stay! Also welcome to Vyxal too :D

Comment: Dunno Vyxal well enough but wonder if you can get combinations without replacement of length n first for the same byte count and then drop the `t` since we may output a list of all of them?

Answer (score 12):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 32 bytes

Using Sylvester's sequence A000058

```
Nest[##&[#^2+#,1+#,##2]&,1,#-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y@1uCRaWVktWjnOSFtZxxCIlZWNYtV0DHWUdQ1j1f4HFGXmlTho@WQWA8l0fYdqQx1jHRMdUx2z2v//AQ)

-8 bytes from @att

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y@1uCRaWVktWjnOSFtZxxCIlZWNYtV0DHWUdQ1j1f4HFGXmlTho@WQWA8l0fYdqQx1jHRMdUx2z2v//AQ) returning a `Sequence` in descending order ([34 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277v9ovtbgkWllZLVo5zkhbWccQiJWVjWLVdAx1lHUNY2vV/gcUZeaVOGil6ztUG@oY65jomOqY1f7/DwA) for list output)

Answer (score 9):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 48 bytes

```
[ 1 - 2 [ 3 dupn . sq - abs 1 + ] repeat 1 - . ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxDoJAEEbhnlP8vYEETSjgAIbGxlgRihEG2bgO6@xQyOVXQvu@N9Fgi6bHvb1da3zIZrxYWMm7jcwtEvFmFfYIyma/oE4MTZZVqUOJHGd0uGBcg6BA/O6FnnGXE3ooByY7tgJ9Gsj79Ac)

Port of @ZaMoC's [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241226/97916). It prints the first n terms of Sylvester's sequence, subtracting 1 from the last number.

The old way that doesn't quite work:

```
[ [1,b] dup 1 rotate v* ]
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>44</s> 38 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen*

```r
function(n)2^(1:n)*.75^(n:1<3)-(n<2)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT9MoTsPQKk9TS8/cNE4jz8rQxlhTVyPPxkhT3@i/RoVtmoaxpiYXV3FproahfoXmfwA)

### First Attempt

```r
function(n){k<-1:n;2^k*.75^(k>n-2)-(n==1)/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT7M620bX0CrP2ihOI1tTS8/cFEjb5ekaaepq5NnaGmrqG9X@16iwTdMw0dTk4iouzdUw1K/Q/A8A)

Port of my Excel answer.

Comment: This is great, and I think you can save some more bytes by scrapping the definition of ```k``` and flipping the ```1:n>n-2``` to ```n:1<3```, [like this](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT9MoTsPQKk9TS8/cNE4jz8rQxlhTVyPP1tZQU9/ov0aFbZqGmaYmF1dxaa6GoX6F5n8A)

Comment: ...and [one more](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT9MoTsPQKk9TS8/cNE4jz8rQxlhTVyPPxkhT3@i/RoVtmoaZpiYXV3FproahfoXmfwA) by changing ```n==1``` to ```n<2```...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have a lot to learn about R.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>70 40</s> 34 bytes

```ruby
->n{a=1;(2..n).map{a*=q=1+a;q}<<a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOtHW0FrDSE8vT1MvN7GgOlHLttDWUDvRurDWxiax9n@0oY6WsZ6eoUEsWLqmoqZAIS26Irb2PwA)

Based on dingledooper's python answer.
Some bytes saved by following Kevin Cruijssen's advice.

Comment: `a*=a+1` can be `a*=q`, right?

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 57 bytes

*Edit: Thanks to Anders Kaseorg (and +2 bytes) for bug-spotting*

```r
function(n){while(n<-n-1)T=c((k=T[1]+1)*T[1],k,T[-1]);+T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY1BCsIwEEX3vYabGdugs1Vzi@xKKSFMbYiOJUkpRTx7tHoBV/8/Po8fi5Wer@uU/acM0brsH9JHniInlmw31GWY5TuA4HMZ/Y1BLkoUodEOIGjTUlcT7rdsQmNaRR2ea/MqYCUtHPUfN0BHxKrauZFdOFVpvgMdfjqWNw)

Outputs one egyptian fractional representation of 1 using n fractions, constructed using [ZaMoC's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241226/95126) & [dingledooper's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241234/95126) approach.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 102 bytes

```r
function(n,m=n){while(all(F<-apply(l<-combn(1:m,n),2,function(k)sum(prod(k)/k)-prod(k))))m=m+1;l[,!F]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BCsIwFET3vYW4@R9TSl1JNdtewKVIiTG1pclPSFJKEc8eqxS3zuoNwwzjk3rMLvaCmtYLGXtLjVfOq6Aoio/lqR3pGwAxwwmfU9drBUJrqE@5cE7PoE@5tOZGUFaGEbI9@5UGDKMB5@19wWLAfMVFhptdedQXtqmvrwSCwqQ8/3cIDohZtpWdkkOVeTudRxOgLOI6gJje)

A brute-force approach that outputs the egyptian fractional representation(s) with the lowest-valued top denominator, by trying all combinations of fractions up to successively increasing denominators.

Comment: The 55, 29, and 24-byte solutions do not work for \$n = 6\$. The denominators must be distinct.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg - Thanks for spotting!  I think it's fixed now!

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υ⊕∨Πυ¹⊞υ⊖⊟υＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxDoMwDEDRnVNktKUwMDBlbBeWkiukwVUqhQSZuNc3pVLF/N@PKXCsIau@KhuYyibtIeuTGBCNlz2BWDOVyLRSabTAzOC5LhIbCFozIKLr/vBOF/R1@4pf5XdpcAv7uaBTHbX/5AM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses a formula for Sylvester's sequence taken from A000058.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop `n` times...

```
⊞υ⊕∨Πυ¹
```

... push the incremented product of the list to the list. (Note that the version of Charcoal on TIO can't take the product of an empty list, so I have to manually replace the result with `1`.)

```
⊞υ⊖⊟υ
```

Decrement the last element of the list.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output the list.

14 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO that can take the product of an empty list:

```
ＦＮ⊞υ⊕Πυ⊞υ⊖⊟υＩυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjeT0_KLFDQ88wpKS_xKc5NSizQ0NRUCSoszNEp1FDzzkotSc1PzSlJTNAKK8lNKk0s0SjU1Na25YCpcUpFU5BfAZIsy80o0nBOLwcqtlxQnJRdDLdwUraRblqOko6CkmwkiTZVioTIA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 47 bytes

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(A1),0.75^(x>A1-2)*2^x-(A1=1)/2)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJngB37bnH6DTyorgt?e=vJmlht)

Uses the fact that for \$ n>2\$: $$\sum_{k=1} ^{n-2} \left(\frac 1 {2}\right) ^ k + \frac 4 {3}\left(\left(\frac 1 {2}\right)^{n-1} + \left(\frac 1 {2}\right)^n\right) = 1$$.

Comment: Drop the leading `0` for -1 byte

Comment: Thanks @TaylorRaine.  Excel puts the 0 back in.  Does that could toward the byte count?

Comment: For Access, Excel and all VBA variants - yes, [AutoFormatting is considered valid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10258) - note, however, that [AutoCompetion is not considered valid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10258). To give an Excel example, you could consider omitting leading the `0` in `0.75` as AutoFormatting, but omitting trailing `)`s and having to clear the `We found a typo in your formula ...` dialog box would be AutoCompletion, and thus invalid.

Comment: So to sum it all up - you can post your formula without the `0` in it, and without it contributing to your byte count. You may want to note that that's happening in your Live Excel sheet tho

Answer (score 5):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>106</s> <s>105</s> 98 bytes

```
(load library
(d g(q((n x)(i(e n 1)x(g(s n 1)(c(*(a(h x)1)(h x))(c(a(h x)1)(t x
(d f(q((n)(g n(q(1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxDoAgEAR7X3HlYkfjf1AELyGoQAGvP4HCamdnky0cW@D8iCDcxlLgPZnUFljyeIFIVYFxUiStKjzyJBxYYXD1tZcRQ/2iUB0Pbj4oeIqdtMDRpuQD)

Not sure there's a better way to <s>get `(1)` than `(c 1()`</s> (use `(q(1`)  add two elements to a list than `(c X(c Y Z)`.

Ports e.g., [Dominic van Essen's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241249/67312).

Thanks to DLosc for -5 bytes.

Comment: Uses `library` just for `*`...

Comment: You can save some bytes on parentheses by inverting the condition: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDoAgEAR7X7Hlnh2N/0EQJCGoYIGvRzQWNpvJTjJnSFcMZW@NcdMWMcxZ52ughedBJlRh4IIEJZWe5SUajtRQXLuXb83vOVGfhnsbQo/USTU6TNJu "tinylisp – Try It Online")

Comment: @DLosc thanks! Found another couple as well. I'm enjoying this LoTM so far, but tinylisp will either help me get over [this](https://xkcd.com/859/) or make it worse

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
⁸P‘ṭƊ¡’0¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4oG4UOKAmOG5rcaKwqHigJkwwqb//zQ)

Based on the Sylvester sequence.

Answer (score 4):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>156</s> <s>97</s> 91 bytes

*-59 bytes remove extra spaces and use pow function*

*-6 bytes thanks to @DLosc*

```
(load library
(d g(q((n m)(i m(c(/(*(s 4(l(s n 2)m))(pow 2 m))4)(g n(s m 1)))(
q((n)(g n n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw7CoAwEITh3lNMOWvjEzyPGpRAsj5BPH1c0/zNN8zt9Q3@2lNi2EaH4KdzPN@CDisPUhGFHpEzK5a80DNYFa1EEe7bg9Ym0gtXqElEIwb/wZIPMkATFxNYu9wht6klfQ)

### First Attempt

```
(load library
(d p(q((x n)(i n(* x(p x(s n 1)))1
(d g(q((n m)(i m(c(/(*(i(l m (s n 1))4 3)(p 2 m))4)(g n(s m 1)))(
(d f(q((n)(g n n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDoMwDER3vuLGM0ubwg/RIlCkxATSAb4@dSKx1ZZvuef39XoFn1MpDNs0I/j3MR1XxxmJO3lChR7KHieTXYbCiYiryFoRRaxI5IcP9vQMiLi5EYPY38sYGYWrmbLV1cBqWJqhFbZ/pwMKF3uB5dDSPaX8AA)

Porting into tinylisp.

Comment: Nice! `(i(l m(s n 1))4 3)` -> `(s 4(l(s n 2)m))` for -2 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw5DoAwEEPRnlO49NCw5UIsAkVKhrBIiNOHIc1vnuXb6xv8lXJm2McFwU/neL4VF2w8SEUUekTObFjzgmOwKnqJIkz7g94m4oQb1CSiE4P/YC0HBaCZqwmsQ2nXSv4A "tinylisp – Try It Online") Also, you don't need to count the `(d f` in your score as long as `f` isn't recursive.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
n->[q-(i==n)|i<-[a=1..n],a*=q=1+a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoMwEAXQq3xcJe2MELStC8eLhCxmowTKMEo3Qu8e2917rkflzdsKacZL3jlUEYvfOnNWSX1vhfQmu6S7lqbu7zMYeIEf1T4/dv90WIPFSMiJMBBGwoPwJLwIU4ntAg)

A port of [@ZaMoC's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241226/9288) and [@G B's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241229/9288).

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
$GD>DŠ*})
```

-4 bytes porting [*@GB*'s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241229/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fxd3FzuXoAq1azf//TQE) or [verify the first \$n=10\$ test cases, excluding \$2\$](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/iY@RdVmmvpPCobZKCkv1/w0p3FzuXowu0ajX/6/wHAA).

Alternative 9-byter inspired by *@Neil*'s comment below, which is pretty similar as the current approach above:

```
$EPNIÊ+ˆ¯
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fxTXAz/Nwl/bptkPr//83BQA) or [verify the first \$n=10\$ test cases, excluding \$2\$](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/iY@RdVmmvpPCobZKCkv1/w0rXAL/Kw13ap9sOrf9fq3Noy38A).

**Explanation:**

```python
$         # Push 1 and the input-integer
 G        # Loop input-1 amount of times:
  D       #  Duplicate the current integer
   >      #  Increase this copy by 1
    D     #  Duplicate that as well
     Š    #  Tripleswap the stack from a,b,c to c,a,b
      *   #  Multiply the top two values
 })       # After the loop, wrap all values on the stack into a list
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)


$         # Push 1 and the input-integer
 E        # Loop `N` in the range [1,input]:
  P       #  Push the product of the stack / top
          #  (which will be 1 in the first iteration)
   NIÊ    #  Check that `N` is NOT equal to the input
          #  (0 if it's the final iteration, 1 otherwise)
      +   #  Add that to the product
       ˆ  #  Pop and add it to the global array
        ¯ #  Push the global array for the next iteration
          # (after which the last pushed global array is output implicitly after
          # the loop)
```

Comment: There are at least two bytes to be saved by calculating the sum of reciprocals "by hand" with integer arithmetic

Comment: @ovs Yeah, I had the feeling there was. Porting GB's Ruby answer saves 4 bytes, though. :)

Comment: Yeah that is shorter. For reference I had `...ʒPDy÷OQ`

Comment: @ovs For reference I had `)sFDP>š}ć<š`.

Comment: @Neil Using the global array, that can be done in 10 bytes: ``F¯P>ˆ}¯`<)``, and arranging the order a bit and using the loop-index to determine if we need to increase, it can be an alternative 9-byter: `$EPNIÊ+ˆ¯`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah, of course, the global array; I was racking my brains trying to work out where I was supposed to get an empty array from.

Comment: @Neil Yeah, if you're not using 05AB1E too often I can understand that. Took me at the start a while as well until I remembered to use the global array for empty lists. [Here the relevant 05AB1E tip for 'hidden' predefined variables that can be useful.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96417/52210)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,x=1)=>[,[x],[x*3,x*1.5]][n]||[x*=2,...f(n-1,x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjBDoIwDADQ32mhNFbjac4fWXogyEwNWQ0QswP/Pjm8y/uMv3GbVvvuQ/HX3FqOUKhGwfhMlKqeuhvVTviumooexxnxSsycoQxCFbWF7CtYlGAPuYS@N5y8bL7MvPgbjDIYYmh/)

Making special \$1=\frac 13+\frac 1{1.5}\$ make it bit shorter

Comment: @Giuseppe Because 2 is not a valid input

Comment: Oh I get it now. Have my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to dingledooper*

```python
lambda n:[4-(x>n-3)<<x>>1for x in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKtpEV6PCLk/XWNPGpsLOzjAtv0ihQiEzT6EoMS89VSNPM/Y/SCgPIWSoo2BoqGmlUFCUmVeikKejkAZU9R8A)

### First Attempt, 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:map(lambda x:2**x*(4-(x>n-3))/2, range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCoAgEEbhq8zSEaOyVkLdZaKsIH9FWtjprUXL9/HScx8RtlY/XRKWVQguSFJ/FGe1LlqNjSozmoG5tYayYN8UmKuPmUAnfuoN9R07SvnETTDkv6u@)

Porting to Python.

Comment: Very interesting formula. I can get yours down to 43 bytes: `lambda n:[4-(x>n-3)<<x>>1for x in range(n)]` (`f=` is not necessary for non-recursive lambdas). This makes me hopeful that a 41 in Python exists!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I especially like the use of the bit shifts.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 26 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{1≡⍵:1⋄3≡⍵:2 3 6⋄2,2×∇⍵-1}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=qzZ81LnwUe9WK8NH3S3GULaRgrGCGZBvpGN0ePqjjnagmK5hLQA&f=Szu0wlDBWMFEwRQA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

A dfn submission which encodes the inductive proof posted in the comments: to get a solution for `n+1`, double each of the denominators and add `2` to the denominators.

E.g. `2 3 6` solves `3` → `2 4 6 12` solves `4` → `2 4 8 12 24` solves `5` → ...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 48 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Dck7DoMwDADQ68QlseoiFtKkB0EZIj6RK2ojqCpunzK86b3zLx/jztvXiU5zrSVIiM5JpNdAFhGLEUj4yZs5QzxvD@jlGuxsm/qBUvWL7oYDeX7S3TcNw6hy6DrjqsWwvQD4@gc)

```js
f=n=>--n>1?[1,...f(n)].map(x=>x*2):n?[1.5,3]:[1]
```

Original answer (49 bytes):

```js
f=n=>[[1],,[2,3,6]][--n]||[2,...f(n).map(x=>x*2)]
```

Comment: 47 bytes: `f=n=>['1',,'236'][--n]||[1,...f(n)].map(x=>x*2)`

Comment: @pxeger It returns string instead of array for n=1,n=3

You inspired me to a shorter solution. I updated the answer.

Comment: I thought output as a string was fine, but up to you I guess

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 105 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU87T8MwEN77Kz5ZHWzillq8U1wJFlSJAaliAoRMmhRD4iS2WxVF@e3BSSsWlrvT3fc6l6hcdeXHV5p4PCmrH6qlWfVLNCNgnWYolDZU2Y2LcWet@nlZeavN5o3FeDbaQw5IYKdyaFNt/aN2/bZvVHCccZxzXHBcclxxXHPccIgZGw2sP8Y0K22qkk80MJCL4QhUwcrnhjoyNnDbolBm7WLC/p1FcBw3GTVsWqiK7uWCiFMSRfupLw@BWfF9GChBBMJavJqjUBtq2/XPBoF4aTyTVMCXOKppuWh2ykLxWt7rTQBQIgibh8j0/XYyQDVr1Ims57UUkWrn9YTqLBClYQJp7lLMWMv6MGndtd0v)

```scala
def f(n:Int)=(1 to n).map(i=>{var a,q=BigInt("1");for(_<-1 to i){a*=q;q=1+a};q-(if(i==n)1 else 0)}).toSeq
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU9dS8MwFH3vrziEPSQumyt@FzvQFxn4IAyf5pC4tTPapl2Sjcnob@@SttYHA5fkntxz7jlmJTJR18XHV7KyeBFaPpUzNfcojgGwTlLkQioq9MZEeNBa/CzmVku1WbIIr0paxM0ksBcZpCp39lkaj/qLhhwXHJccVxzXHDcctxx3HOGEBQ2rZ4zTQidi9YkjFOJp8wmUbpXNFDVkoGB2eS7U2kSE/fsO3cbBMaWKjXNR0kM8JeE5GQ4PY1u0hln@3T4owRCEVXhTnVAV@OryOo0IM2VdPu9r8Sg3rlv2OWkIW6Dd48zKP7N7oSH41k22HErC3qlLB/qO@xEaumSdmj8CZzG2fesFQmdRdEgV/OIjUJm6Qhw7A24oyUyCSRfCJfWGmyxVUNcn)

```scala
object PariGpInScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val inputList = List(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

    inputList.foreach { n =>
      println(s"$n summands:")
      println(s"1 = ${f(n).map(x=>"1/"++x.toString)mkString(" + ")} \n")
    }
  }

  def f(n: Int): List[BigInt] = {
    (1 to n).map { i =>
      var a,q = BigInt("1")
      for (_ <- 1 to i) {
        a *= q
        q = 1 + a
      }
      q - (if (i == n) 1 else 0)
    }.toList
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 80 chars

```
r←z w;k;t
r←⍬⋄→0×⍳2≥w⋄r←2 3 6
→3×⍳w=k←≢r⋄t←r[k]÷6⋄r[k]←t×t+6⋄r,←6×t+6⋄→2
r←r[⍋r]
```

10+20+43+7=80. It return ⍬ if w≤2, 2 3 6 if w=3, otherwise it use the formula

```
1/r*s=(1/(r*(r+s)))+(1/s*(r+s))
```

for make more long
the array of start 2 3 6. z has the peculiarity could calculate easly the result at last for argument <= 20000, because the numbers
are not big numbers there will be a problem for the argument too much big, when  `r*(r+s)` or `s*(r+s)` will be too much big.

```
  z 3
2 3 6 
  z 2

  z 4
2 3 7 42 
  z 20
2 3 7 91 247 475 618 775 1147 1591 2107 2695 3355 4087 4891 5767 6715 7735 8827 9991 
  +/÷z 20
1
  +/÷z 20000
1
```